# What is the MinValue of Byte[] in C#

Tags: max, varbinary

We represent MinValue of DateTime as DateTime.MinValue but how is it represented for Byte[]?

When I gave the below,

```
DALImage.TwinImage = Convert.IsDBNull(reader["TwinImage"]) ? 
    Byte[].MinValue : 
    (Byte[])reader["TwinImage"];
```

1. I get the error as 'byte' is a type but use like a variable
2. syntax error value expected (in '[]' part of Byte[])

Please Help as am a newbie to C# programming

Comment: Well it depends what you want? Either use `null` or `Byte[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array of bytes doesn't have a minimum value - it doesn't make sense as a concept. It's like asking "What's the minimum value of a shopping list".

I think what you are trying to do is get an **empty** Byte array.

```
DALImage.TwinImage = Convert.IsDBNull(reader["TwinImage"]) ? 
    new Byte[0] : 
    (Byte[])reader["TwinImage"];
```

**EDIT**:
Your comment suggests that what you actually want is a byte array with 1 element in it, where that element is the minimum value of a byte.

That would be the following code:

```
DALImage.TwinImage = Convert.IsDBNull(reader["TwinImage"]) ? 
    new Byte[1] { Byte.MinValue } : 
    (Byte[])reader["TwinImage"];
```

However, this could also be written using [default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/83fhsxwc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is probably semantically cleaner.

```
DALImage.TwinImage = Convert.IsDBNull(reader["TwinImage"]) ? 
    new Byte[1] { default(Byte) } : 
    (Byte[])reader["TwinImage"];
```

Comment: Thank yo uso much. Both work. But how do we say that Byte[0] has the min value?

Comment: @user2138814 I've updated my post to answer that, but are you *sure* this is what you want? I'm pretty sure you want an empty byte array, not a 1-element array with a default value...